# angular2 read xml from text file in project folder

Tags: xml, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

In my project folder there is a text file which contains a xml string,i need to read the string from the files so that i can parse it a xml and use it in my program.please help me out.

```
<groupDirectory>
<directoryDetails>
<userId>extn5001</userId>
<firstName>Park</firstName>
<lastName>1</lastName>
<groupId>communications</groupId>
<extension>5001</extension>
</directoryDetails>
<directoryDetails>
<userId>Yealinkt27ptest</userId>
<firstName>Yealink T</firstName>
<lastName>27P</lastName>
<groupId>communications</groupId>
<extension>4676</extension>
</directoryDetails>
<groupDirectory>
```

this is the xml i have stored in a .txt file i need to read the contents of this file(XML) from program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort at all.